# Please redirect [tagging] to [tags]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

As per [Redirect tags to [tags]](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/redirect-tags-to-tags), can we make [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) a synonym of [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) to keep things consistent here on Meta?

Comment: [retagging] also, I think.

Comment: I have tried to add the synonym but failed: one needs also to have at least 5 total vote to answers with the tag to be authorized to propose a synonym, large rep and asking questions is not sufficient. So in the meantime, I retagged all `tagging`to `tags`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these posts have been edited through to remove the tag, a tag cleanup script has since run so the tag doesn't actually exist anymore.  If it comes back a synonym could be considered.